# Best way to switch values

Tags: ruby

I would like to find the most effective and short way to do the following:

```
if current_value == "hide"
  current_value   = "show"
elsif current_value == "show"
 current_value     = "hide"
end
```

So, i would like to set the opposite to what the current situation is.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about ternary?

```
current_value == "hide" ? current_value = "show" : current_value = "hide"
```

Maybe this would be better :

```
current_value = (current_value == "hide") ? "show" : "hide"
```

Comment: No need for the inner assignments. You can do `current_value = (current_value == hide) ? "show" : "hide"`

Comment: Do `current_value = (current_value == "hide") ? "show" : "hide"`. Don't rely on Ruby.. Be safe :)

Comment: I will take this one. It is pure ruby love :).
I was thinking in this way but have never user it with value = x ==
I somehow thought it will brake! Love it.

Answer (score 3):

Four ways:

```
#1
c = 'show'
c = c['hide'] ? 'show' : 'hide'

#2
c = case c
  when 'hide' then 'show'
  else 'show'
end

#3
c, = ['show','hide']-[c]

#4
show = ['show', 'hide'].cycle

p show.next #=> 'show'
p show.next #=> 'hide'
p show.next #=> 'show'
```

Comment: +1 i like the first one.. But How `cycle`, helps this post. How would you check `current_value` and then do assignment with `cycle` ?

Comment: The last version wont work if you have other functions that set the variable, but if you only use this way you can simply use `show.first` as `current_value`.

Answer (score 2):

One way that is not too pretty but will work:

```
current_value = (["hide", "show"] - [current_value])[0]
```

Comment: Oh, this is actually quite interesting, but not pretty, i agree :)

Answer (score 2):

If current_value can only be "show" or "hide", why don't you use a boolean variable, say is_visible?

Then just toggle it like this:

```
is_visible = !is_visible
```

Comment: No, it can be a CSS class, for example. Alternate between red/blue, or whatever.

Comment: It is actually saved in DB as user setting

Comment: @SergioTulentsev even in that case I think it's preferable to use a Boolean and then convert to a string when needed. `is_visible ? 'show' : 'hide'` is much more readable.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
VALUES = {
  'show' => 'hide',
  'hide' => 'show',
}
current_value = VALUES[current_value]
```

Another unorthodox approach :)

```
VALUES = %w[hide show hide]

current_value = 'show'
current_value = VALUES[VALUES.index(current_value) + 1] # => "hide"
```

Comment: In fact I prefer my version to this one. Not only because of the obvious reason that it is mine( ;) ), but because it avoids typing twice "show" and "hide", which is annoying and may be hard to maintain in case you decide to change `show` to `unhide` for instance

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev: it's just thinking out of the box :) In my code I'd do the ternary.

Comment: Oh just saw your second answer... I did the same with -1

Answer (score 1):

I think the right way to go is to keep a boolean value like Yanhao suggests, and if you are to call that in a CSS class, use a ternary there.

```
current_value = true # initial setting
...
current_value ^= true # alternating between `true` and `false`
...
current_value ? "hide" : "show" # using it to call a string value
```

Answer (score 1):

A way that can be reused more easily (edit toggle values more easily)

```
c = 'show'

TOGGLE_VALUES = ['show', 'hide']

c = TOGGLE_VALUES[ TOGGLE_VALUES.index(c) - 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

When one is late to the party (this is answer #8), one must dig deep. The best solution does not often result, but the grey cells do get some exercise.  Here are a few more ways to flip 'show' and 'hide' (in no particular order):

```
SH = 'showhide'
a = ['show', 'hide']
h = {'show'=>'hide'}

c = 'show'
```

1

```
c = SH.sub(c,'')                                 #=> 'hide'
```

2

```
c = SH[/.+(?=#{c})|(?<=#{c}).+/]                 #=> 'hide'
```

3

```
c = (SH.end_with? c) ? "show" : "hide"           #=> 'hide'
```

4

```
d = "hide"     
c, = (c,d = d,c)                                 #=> 'hide'
```

5

```
c = SH.chomp(c).reverse.chomp(c.reverse).reverse #=> 'hide'
```

6

```
c, = a.reverse!                                  #=> 'hide'
```

7

```
c = (h=h.invert)[c]                              #=> 'hide'
```

In #2, `(?=#{c})` and `(?<=#{c})` are positive lookahead and positive lookbehind, respectively.